# java.io.FileNotFoundException When trying to load a file I just saved

Tags: android

I'm trying to save and then load the files that I've just saved but I can't find it.

I know it is being saved because I can look at the cache size under the Manage Application screen for the app and see that the size goes up when I save the image.

This is the error I'm getting: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.xxxxx/files/5ec2d71d-8a99-4258-a33a-91f6f99b8f0e.jpg`

Here is my code:

```
imageDir = new File(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
            String newName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg";
            Bitmap bmp = ImageLoader.getInstance().getBitmap(e.getUrl());


            Boolean r = imageDir.exists();
            Boolean c = imageDir.canWrite();
            String[] d = imageDir.list();

            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(imageDir + "/" + newName));
            bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            d = imageDir.list();

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageDir + "/" + newName);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Bitmap b = (Bitmap) ois.readObject();
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Context.openFileInput` opens files within your app's data directory. What is the point of that call anyway? You already created a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: EboMike, thanks for the question. I clarified my code by splitting it how I actually have it in my project.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't clarify anything. Why are you calling openFileInput? What happens when you just take that call out?

Comment: I took it out and now I get java.io.StreamCorruptedException.  I also updated my code. I'm looking into the new error now...

Comment: I think you want to use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` on the fis. Don't use ObjectInputStream.

Comment: Oh you rock EboMike! That did it! This is what it looks like:   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageDir + "/" + newName);
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

Comment: Yep. Simpler is better :) BitmapFactory is your best friend, by the way. Glad to help!